# Show/Link variation

Tags: magento2.3, related-products

Just want to start by saying thank you for taking the time to read this.

I'm wondering if there is any possible way to link or show variation/simple products tied to a configurable product? Like when choosing a 'related product' or for a homepage widget using a conditional.

EXAMPLE: I have a 'Cotton T-Shirt' (product A), that is the configurable product. Then I have a 'Red' T-shirt tied to the 'Cotton T-Shirt' (product A). So, 'product A' with a variation of A1 and more like A2, A3, A4, etc.

Product A

- Product A1
- Product A2
- Product A3
- Product A4

Product B

etc.

There are several places (related, product widgets for homepage, etc.) in Magento that let you pick a product for display (ie. by conditional). While choosing, it always allows you to pick ANY product, like variation 'A2' or 'A4' and of course 'product A'. BUT, my problem: why does it let you choose a variation if it does not work? Like if I choose a SKU (or ID) that is a variation (A3), it just simply does not show. But if I choose the configurable product (product A), it works.

My point is this: It would be incredibly amazing to be able to showcase variations (say a camo t-shirt goes with the same style camo pants, both are variations of a different configurable product). Say 'product F' with variation 'F2' related to 'product M' variation 'M9'. Not how it is currently: 'product F' related to 'product M' - too basic.

Related would benefit too if we could choose variations instead of just a 'top' product, it would help to showcase certain colors/styles for a product. As it is now, it simply just shows the main product which isn't incredibly helpful.

Am I missing something somewhere? Hopefully...but if not is there someway I can tweak this to make it work like that?

Much appreciate any help in advance, I think this would be a big benefit to others as well if a solution could be found...

Thanks!